# MS Access OrderBy with If then clause to vary sort in one detail section

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a three column table, JobStatus, DeliveryDate, JobSize

I want to order by JobStatus (A | B | C) then DeliveryDate (soonest first) then JobSize (largest first) for jobs due within the next 5 days.
After the 5 days, then order by only JobDate.

OrderBy for the first part is as follows,

`Me.ScheduleForm.Form.OrderBy = "[JobStatus], [DeliveryDate], [JobSize] DESC"`

But how would you incorporate a change of OrderBy clause for the non-urgent jobs with DeliverDate > 5 days away ?

Here is what I want to do in psuedo code:

`Me.ScheduleForm.Form.OrderBy = "if ([DeliverDate] - [Today] < '5 days')

      then ([JobStatus], [DeliveryDate], [JobSize] DESC)

      else ([DeliveryDate]) "`

Comment: Iif and datediff can probably used here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you'll need to build a string that can be sorted ASCending and cover both cases. The general form would be something like

IIf(DateDiff("d", Date(), [DeliveryDate]) <= 5, *StringExpression1*, *StringExpression2*)

where *StringExpression1* would start with "A" (so they come first) and include all the fields...

"A" & [JobStatus] & Format([DeliveryDate], "yyyy-mm-dd") & Format(999999 - [JobSize], "000000")

...and *StringExpression2* would start with "B" (so they come last) and contain just the 
[DeliveryDate] with constant placeholders for the other fields...

"B" & " " & Format([DeliveryDate], "yyyy-mm-dd") & "000000"

Comment: Thanks for this Gord. I can see what it is trying to do. The Format... aspect doesn't behave as expected. The query works OK with [JobSize] only but adding the Format(99 ...) part sets OrderBy to something that I can't even see what it is ordering by. I'll post what I have. Me.ScheduleSubform.Form.OrderBy = "IIf(DateDiff(""d"", Now, DeliveryDate) > 5, ""B""&"" ""&[DeliveryDate]&""000000"", ""A""&[JobStatus]&[DeliveryDate]&Format(999999 - [JobSize], ""000000"")"

Comment: @NickT The `Format()` function calls were included to make sure that the computer's date format in Windows' Regional Settings don't mess up the sorting. If including them causes unexpected results then a workaround would be to include the sort string as a separate column in a saved query, base the report on that query, and set the `.OrderBy` property to the name of the column.